# Putty proxy connection from the command line

Tags: putty

I CAN connect to an internet SSH system using the PUTTY GUI (I'm on a Windows box) by using a corporate proxy connection which allows for a SOCKS5 proxy connection on port 1080.

How can I also emulate the above connection from the command line? What is the syntax?

I have attempted a combination (even concatenating them) of putty and plink (-nc host:port) commands without success.
Many thanks!